# Python ARIMA- Output Prediction Intervals for Time Series

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am trying to produce a time series forecast and have it output prediction intervals (not confidence intervals) After several attempts I used this code below:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from itertools import product
from datetime import timedelta

# Usage
series_path = "C:\\mydirectory\myfile.csv"
ts_forecast = TimeSeriesForecast(series_path)
best_order = ts_forecast.find_best_order()
forecast, prediction_intervals = ts_forecast.calculate_prediction_intervals(best_order, alpha_levels=[0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20])
ts_forecast.plot_original_series(forecast, forecast_variance, prediction_intervals, best_order)

class TimeSeriesForecast:
    def __init__(self, series_path):
        self.series = read_csv(series_path, header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)


    def find_best_order(self, max_order=(5, 2, 2)):
        best_aic = np.inf
        best_order = None


        for order in product(range(6), repeat=3):
            if order > max_order:
                continue
            try:
                model = ARIMA(self.series, order=order)
                model_fit = model.fit()
                aic = model_fit.aic
                if aic < best_aic:
                    best_aic = aic
                    best_order = order
            except:
                continue


        return best_order


    def difference_series(self, order):
        seasonal_diff = 0
        for i in range(order[1]):
            seasonal_diff += self.series.diff(i+1).dropna()
        return seasonal_diff


    def calculate_prediction_intervals(self, order, alpha_levels=[0.05], plot=True):
        if isinstance(order, str) and order.lower() == 'auto':
            order = self.find_best_order()


        seasonal_diff = self.difference_series(order)


        # Define the prediction horizon
        n_forecast_steps = len(seasonal_diff)


        # Fit an ARIMA model
        model = ARIMA(seasonal_diff, order=order)
        model_fit = model.fit()


        # Get the point forecast
        forecast = model_fit.forecast(steps=n_forecast_steps)
        forecast_variance = model_fit.forecast_variance(steps=n_forecast_steps)

        # Calculate standard error for the forecast
        stderr = np.sqrt(model_fit.forecast_variance(steps=n_forecast_steps))


        # Calculate prediction intervals
        prediction_intervals = {}
        for alpha in alpha_levels:
            z_alpha = norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2)
            lower = forecast - z_alpha * stderr
            upper = forecast + z_alpha * stderr
            prediction_intervals[alpha] = (lower, upper)


            # Print prediction intervals
            print(f'%.1f%% Prediction Interval: {forecast[-1]:.3f} between {lower[-1]:.3f} and {upper[-1]:.3f}')


        # Plot the forecasts and prediction intervals
        if plot:
            plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
            plt.plot(seasonal_diff.index, seasonal_diff, label='Differenced Series', color='blue')
            plt.plot(forecast.index, forecast, label='Forecast', color='red')
            for alpha in alpha_levels:
                lower, upper = prediction_intervals[alpha]
                plt.fill_between(forecast.index, lower, upper, alpha=0.2, label=f'{int((1-alpha)*100)}% Prediction Interval')
            plt.xlabel('Date')
            plt.ylabel('Differenced Value')
            plt.legend()
            plt.title('ARIMA Forecast with Prediction Intervals')
            plt.show()


        return forecast, prediction_intervals


    def plot_original_series(self, forecast, prediction_intervals, order):
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
        plt.plot(self.series.index, self.series, label='Original Series', color='blue')
        forecast_index = pd.date_range(start=self.series.index[-1], periods=len(forecast)+1, closed='right')[1:]
        plt.plot(forecast_index, forecast, label='Forecast', color='red')
        alpha = list(prediction_intervals.keys())[0]
        lower, upper = prediction_intervals[alpha]
        prediction_index = pd.date_range(start=self.series.index[-1] + timedelta(days=1), periods=len(lower), closed='right')
        plt.fill_between(prediction_index, lower, upper, alpha=0.2, label=f'{int((1-alpha)*100)}% Prediction Interval')
        plt.xlabel('Date')
        plt.ylabel('Value')
        plt.legend()
        plt.title(f'ARIMA Forecast with Prediction Intervals (Order {order})')
        plt.show()


# Usage
series_path = "C:\\Users\\smithw4\\OneDrive - American Water\\Documents\\Fem Proj data 2024.csv"
ts_forecast = TimeSeriesForecast(series_path)
best_order = ts_forecast.find_best_order()
forecast, forecast_variance, prediction_intervals = ts_forecast.calculate_prediction_intervals(best_order, alpha_levels=[0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20])
ts_forecast.plot_original_series(forecast, forecast_variance, prediction_intervals, best_order)
```

I keep getting this error 'ARIMAResults' object has no attribute 'forecast_variance' that I have not been able to resolve.   What am I missing? Please advise . -- Thanks!

Comment: In which line specifically does this error occur?

Comment: Hi-- the error occurs  at the line:

 # Calculate standard error for the forecast
        stderr = np.sqrt(model_fit.forecast_variance(steps=n_forecast_steps))

Comment: Short answer is that the `ARIMAResults` object that `model.fit()` returns has no attribute 'forecast_variance', meaning it has no function to compute that (see [doc](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults)). As to why that is, could be that you're using a different version of statsmodels and there's a different method to get the forecaset variance.